# How call form from another form?

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have "login" form. My submit button checks username and password. I want this button also close "login" form and open another form where form name comes from label caption. For example:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "label11.caption"
```

But I get error. and cannot solve this. 
Please help 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should read:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm Me!label11.Caption
```